# Recreating something in Vue that I did in React

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, ionicons

I'm working on my own personal portfolio and I have my social media saved as a template to just pull from using this code in React.

```
  {this.state.contact.map((contact, index) => 
                <a className="social-icons" href={`${contact.href}`} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" key={index}>
                    <h3 className={`ion-social-${contact.title}`}></h3>
                </a>
            )}
```

I'm trying to create the same effect while using Vue for the ion-social-icons but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to implement it as I just receive an error talking about using v-bind:class that doesn't help much. This is what I'm currently trying.

```
 <p class="social-media snippet ion-social-{{social.title}}" v-for="social in socials" v-bind:key="social">
  {{ social.title }}
</p>
```

I'm relatively new to Vue also.

Answer (score 3):

The error you get is:

```
Interpolation inside attributes has been removed. Use v-bind or the colon shorthand instead. 
For example, instead of <div class="{{ val }}">, use <div :class="val">.
```

Off the top of my head, there are 3 ways to set an html attribute in Vue.

1. You want to set a string literal. Just write it as if you were writing regular HTML.

   `class="myClass"`.  You cannot interpolate javascript here, which is what you're trying to do and what Vue was warning about.
2. You want to use a javascript variable defined in your component. Use `v-bind`.

   `v-bind:class="myClassVariable"`
3. Same as above, where `:` is just a shortcut for `v-bind`.

   `:class="myClassVariable"`

A working example of your class binding looks like this,

`<p class="social-media snippet" :class="'ion-social-'+social.title" ...`

The value inside `:class="..."` is simply an expression, where `'ion-social'` is a string literal that's appended with the variable `social.title`. Once your template gets messy, which imo it is now, you should remove logic from your template and put it inside the component.

Answer (score 1):

Using interpolations in HTML attributes was possible in Vue 1.0, but is no longer supported since 2.0. Here, you need to use v-bind, then add the variable with the string like you would in JS.

```
<p
  v-for="social in socials"
  v-bind:class="'social-media snippet ion-social-' + social.title"
  v-bind:key="social"
>
  {{ social.title }}
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer!


`<div class="social-media snippet" v-for="social in socials" v-bind:key="social">
      <a v-bind:href="[social.href]" target="_blank">
        <i class="icon" v-bind:class="[social.ion]">
        </i>
      </a>
    </div>` 

I ended up trying this and this also worked!